# Android Sutido 3.4 problem of including jni.h

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I upgrade Android Studio 3.2 to 3.4 and encounter a problem. 
Add a `test.cpp` source file to CMakelist and Sync project but it doesn't work. Android Studio prompt me:

> This file is not part of the project. Please include it int the appropriate build file(build.gradle, CMakeList.txt or Android.mk etc) and sync the project

When I build the project. the cpp source works. and when I include `jni.h`. the `jni.h` has red alert. But compiles for no problem. The existing cpp files have no such problem. They include `jni.h` successfully and have no red alert. 
Could you tell me what happens. Does Android Studio 3.4 have a bug?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55826287/android-studio-this-file-not-part-of-the-project-but-the-project-builds-succes) it help me. I change ndk version and sync then revert it back to original version. It work for me. But I am very confused why does it happened

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the IDE caches and project iml file, i.e. the `.idea` and `.gradle` and `.iml` under your project root dir.