# "This file is not part of the project Please include it in the appropiate build file(build.gradle, CMakeLists.txt....)

Tags: android-studio

I am new to Android Studio and couldn't solve this problem. I wrote a cpp code with it's header file, but even though I added the cpp file to CMakeLists.txt, I still get this error.

How can I include my cpp file to a build file?

Comment: This question is related with Android NDK, so please mention it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55847574/9523118 checkout this link

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by:

**Step1:** First make sure you added the **CMakeLists.txt** inside "**app**" folder.

**Step2:** Check the below image. Choose the option "**Link C++ Project with Gradle**" with your cpp file.

[image]

**Step3:** A new window gets opened. Just add the path there for **CMakeLists.txt**.

In **build.gradle** below entry get created automatically:

```
externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('CMakeLists.txt')
        }
    }
```

**Step4:** Go to File and choose option **"Invalidate Caches / Restart..."**

After Android Studio get restarted, this issue gets fixed.

Comment: This answer does not work for me, I think because the file is referenced inside an add_custom_command statement in CMakeLists.txt. Android Studio doesn't seem to see a dependency inside an add_custom_command.